# What are the real benefits of stash command?

Tags: git

I came across a `stash` command in git and I really don't understand benefits of such command.

Suppose I created some temporary changes in `foo_branch`, and I want to checkout on `bar_branch`. My usual practise is to create commit with `temp commit` message in `foo_branch`, and then perform checkout on `bar_branch`. Then if I want to come back to `foo_branch`, I perform checkout and discard last commit (preserving changes) of `foo_branch`, then I continue to work.

In my opinion, `stash` command is just another way to do such thing.

What are the real benefits of `stash` command? Maybe is it just shortcut for such case?

Comment: git stash pop can also be executed on bar_branch and pop the stashed changes into the other branch

Comment: Highly underrated question. This is one of the most useful features in git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stash` command can save the current state of the index, the working dir and of untracked files.  It's just a lot quicker to run `git stash` than it is to decide what changes to add to the staging area and commit with a commit message.

Moreover, a stash can be applied in a different position than where it was initially created.  You could do that by temporarily commiting on the current branch, switching to a different branch, cherry-picking your commit, and then removing it from where it was originally created.

It's just a quick way of getting a clean working directory if you need to do something else.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your workflow. In git you can achieve many things using different set of commands.

IMO you can see stash as a commit made locally, without being attached to a particular branch. That is, in a situation when you started work you can stash your changes, fetch new changes, update your branch, make some changes, commit them and play around with git repository freely, and then, pop your saved work from stash. Or you could even pop your work to a different branch.

Comment: In fact, `git stash` does just that: make a commit ... well, really *two* commits, that are not on any branch. Or if you ask it to save "untracked" or "all" files, it even makes *three* commits not-on-any-branch. But I voted for this answer because it's entirely right, and viewing the stash as "commits not on any particular branch" is the right way to view it.

Answer (score 1):

I normally stash changes that I need often, and I don't want to redo them by hand every time.

Use Case: hardcoded api credentials for internal use. I want to use credentials of my user, so I change them once and stash the change. Next time I check out a branch and need to do some api queries, I just apply the stash. (*yeah-yeah, credentials should be in env vars, I know*).

Or you could do the same for, say, debug printing in certain places. They'll never let you commit that. But chances are, you'll need it again.

Answer (score 1):

**Commit is performed in two steps staging and actual commit**

where Staging is like holding changes and storing them in Git before committing the changes

Staging really important incase when you made some changes and you still don't wanna commit it now and want to checkout to specific branch so this changes will deleted then we have to stage it **(store locally in Git to commit Later)**

Answer (score -1):

Here's a visual diagram of the lifecycle status of your files:

[image: Git file lifecycle]